# How do you fix this mysql query without the use of a subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. For the purposes of this example I will simplify it as much as I can.

First table contains movie ids and names, second table contains genre ids and genre names  (action, drama, etc). 3rd table stores the genre id associated with each movie, since some movies have more than one. It has 2 columns, genre_id and movie_id. Fairy simple stuff. Im trying to output the list of movies, along with a list of genres associated with each movie.

```
    SELECT *
        FROM movies
        LEFT JOIN gen_pairs
        ON movies.mov_id = gen_pairs.gen_movieid
        LEFT JOIN categories
        ON gen_pairs.gen_catid = categories.cat_id 
    GROUP BY mov_id
```

This will obviously output a single genre of each film, even if it has multiple ones in the gen_pairs table. How would I get it to display a comma separated list of genres for each movie, without running a sub-query for each item?

Comment: Correction: this will output *ALL* genres for any given film, one genre per row, repeating the film's name for each of the latter's corresponding genres.

Comment: Forgot the GROUP BY clause. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select should build the Cartesian product, so you'll get output like

```
MovieA   GenreA
MovieA   GenreB
MovieB   GenreA
...
```

But it sounds like you want this instead:

```
MovieA   GenreA, GenreB
MovieB   GenreA
...
```

MySQL has a GROUP_CONCAT function to do what you want:

```
SELECT m.mov_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)
       FROM movies m
  LEFT JOIN gen_pairs gp ON (m.mov_id = gp.gen_movieid)
  LEFT JOIN categories c ON (gp.gen_catid = c.cat_id)
  GROUP BY m.mov_id
```

Note the GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY.

Comment: That seems to work. Is there a way to also get a 2nd parameter from the DB (cat_id) and pass them at the same time through an array?

Comment: you could add another group_concat(c.cat_id) to the select list. Other than that, not sure what you mean.